# Django: name 'request' is not defined when try to filter event that has been accepted by User

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to filter an event that is only accepted by the current login-user, however the error  "name 'request' is not defined" continues to pop-up. I have tried self.request user but it's still not working!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from cal.models import Event
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

# formats a day as a td
# filter events by day
def formatday(self, day, events):
    events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day, acceptor=self.request.user )
    d = ''
    for event in events_per_day:


        # filter event that only accepted by user
        if event.acceptor == User:
            d += event.get_absolute_url()   


    if day != 0:
        return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
    return '<td></td>'

# formats a week as a tr 
def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
    week = ''
    for d, weekday in theweek:
        week += self.formatday(d, events)
    return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

def formatmonth(self, withyear=True, ):
    events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

    cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
    cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
    cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
    for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
        cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
    return cal
```

Comment: You inded did not pass the `request` object to your function, hence there is no request (requests are not something magically that is passed implicitly). Probably the best way to fix this is adding the request parameter, and pass this with the caller.

Comment: What is `self` here? Is this a class-based view? In which case you can access `self.request`.

Comment: events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day, acceptor=self.request.user ) I have change to this however, the Calendar' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Well, that's why I asked if it is a view; it isn't, so that won't work. But how is it being called from your view? You need to pass the request in as Willem suggested, either when you instantiate the Calendar or when you call those format methods.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late reply but I face the similar prob recently. Here's my solution:
create a attribute name user or anything to store the id and get that from parameter.

```
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, user=None):
    self.year = year
    self.month = month
    self.user = user
    super(Calendar, self).__init__()
```

like this pass the user when creating the object in views.py

```
user = self.request.user
cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month, user)
```

and then use as you like:

```
 events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day, acceptor=self.user )
```